# Unable to access OEM 11g after upgrading to Firefox ver 37.0.1

Tags: ssl

I upgraded my browser (Firefox) to the latest version 37.0.1. Thereafter, OEM 11g is not accessible. Here are the errors:

`**Secure Connection Failed**
The connection to bdporagrid.bdpinternational.com:7799 was interrupted while the page was loading.
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.`

I did some research and tried many workaround but still unable to get it loaded. I have no problem with Chrome or IE loading the OEM11g webpage.

`The URL is:https://xxxxx.yyyy.com:7799/em/console/targets`

Workaround attempted:

1. Deleted the cert8.db in Firefox profile and then relaunch Firefox. --*Failed to resolve*
2. Delete or Distrust the OEM11g server certificate under Firefox --> Options --> Certificates tab --> View Certificates.
   Relaunch firefox--*Failed to resolve*
3. I exported the OEM11g server certificate using IE. Then, I imported it into Firefox. Same error. --*Failed to resolve*.

Not sure if anyone has a workaround or solution. I am sure ver 37.0.1 has changed the https behavior.

Comment: Is the X.509 certificate is issued by a "Trusted" root CA? CNNIC was recently revoked. Firefox is pushing to phase out 1024-bit RSA certs ( https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/01/28/phase-2-phasing-out-certificates-with-1024-bit-rsa-keys/) and SHA-1 certs ( https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick workaround: Set Firefox's about:config setting *security.tls.version.fallback-limit* to '0'.

The correct way to fix this is to get the site to updated.

Source: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=2925119&start=15

Comment: It worked like a charm! The default value was '3'. Changing to 0 solved!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing security.tls.version.fallback-limit from =3 to =2. I would not go lower than 2 for this setting, if possible.

security.tls.version.fallback-limit=3 means require at least TLS 1.2

security.tls.version.fallback-limit=2 means require at least TLS 1.1

security.tls.version.fallback-limit=1 means require at least TLS 1.0

security.tls.version.fallback-limit=0 means require at least SSL 3.0

For each increment you reduce this setting, you are effectively allowing less and less secure connections.

Instead of dropping directly from TLS 1.2 to SSL 3.0, I would only set this value as low as you need to establish a connection to your site.