# Unable to access OEM 11g grid control after upgrading to Firefox ver 39.0

Tags: oracle

Previously, I have encountered the similar issue after upgrading Firefox to version 37.0.1.

Here's the link of the question posted: [Unable to access OEM 11g after upgrading to Firefox ver 37.0.1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97368/unable-to-access-oem-11g-after-upgrading-to-firefox-ver-37-0-1)

I applied the suggested workaround `Set Firefox's about:config setting security.tls.version.fallback-limit to '0'.` It worked for Firefox version 37.0.1 however, yesterday my firefox was updated automatically to verson 39.0 (I have since disabled the auto update). Everything broken again.

Working around no longer fix. Not sure what Firefox has done with the new release.

Comment: This is more of a ServerFault question or Unix and Linux. Have you tried using Chrome?

Comment: Chrome block the site but offer an option in "Advance" where if I want to proceed with risks. I clicked yes and allowed me through.

Comment: Sometimes it's best not to worry too much. If Chrome works, just stick with it?

Comment: Actually my default browser is Firefox not Chrome. I have all my bookmarks etc and I prefer Firefox than Chrome. I have a workaround for previous Firefox upgrade release. Seems this time running out of luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have finally figured it out. I clicked on [image]

- Opened Help Menu (?)
- Troubleshooting Information
- Refresh Firefox

This would reset the default Firefox configuration. You will lose all your add-ons. Beware!

Next, enter following in browser URL:

```
about:config
```

Change the following settings
`security.tls.version.fallback-limit=1`

Restart firefox.

Viola! OEM loads flawlessly.